# SQL Server 2016 Master Data Services

Tags: sql-server, mds

Can anyone tell me how to change the title of SQL Server 2016 Master Data Services within the web portal. Basically I want to change the "SQL Server 2016" to be my company name.

Can this be achieved?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is based on my knowledge of SQL Server 2012. 2016 may be slightly different.

If you're referring to the "title" in the top-left corner of every page then that is actually an image. In order to change that to another logo image of your choosing you will have to replace that image on the site in the web server. This is how you can achieve this:-

1. Log on to (remote desktop to) the Web Server hosting the MDS site. If you have separate DB & Web servers then this is Not the one where the database is hosted.
2. You now need to go the physical folder where the MDS website is located on the server. If you don't know the exact location then open IIS, locate your MDS site in the tree structure on the left (under *sites*), right-click on your site & click *Explore*.
3. Once you're in the folder, look for a sub-folder named ***Images***. Inside this folder, you will find a file ***logo.png***. This is the file you need to replace. Verify by opening the original file in an image viewer.
4. Backup the original file, add your png file here, rename your file to *logo.png*.
5. You should be set here. In case refreshing the browser page does not bring up the correct logo, then try restarting the site in IIS.

Note: for your new logo image, try to get the same dimensions as the original image on the server (*logo.png*).